# Friendly server hack attempt (to determine vulnerabilities)

Tags: security

I own a Linux VPS, which I use mostly for fun (to teach myself things etc.), while I also have some rather important services there, such as an email stack, a Jabber server, a LAMP stack etc.

I was thinking of an online service, which I could submit my server's IP address to, and the experienced people there could check my box for any vulnerabilities, just for fun, while me having some degree of confidence that they won't actually compromise the box.
Are you aware of anything like that?

I know what nmap is, so don't suggest that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [Sitewatch](https://sitewat.ch/en/About),  they have a free service.

Comment: Thanks. But that's only the HTTP part. They don't go further, like http://hackertarget.com/, to use different tools to scan more aspects of the box. What I actually need is the human factor.

Comment: @Andriy Yurchuk oah yes a human factor will product the best results.  A penetration test costs usually $2,000-$10,000 depending on the company and the size of the project.